# HashiCorp Vault Error 403 Permission denied

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault, hashicorp

Im new to HashiCorp Vault and im Doing the tutorials one by one by far i have cleared installing vault and setting up the server.. I even learnt to create a secret, no problems. Im facing an issue in secret engines.. When i type the command "vault secrets enable -path=kv kv" im getting an error saying "Error enabling: Error making API request.

URL: POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/mounts/kv
Code: 403. Errors:

- permission denied"
  Can anyone pls help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vault denies access to its API endpoints by default. In order to use /sys/mounts/kv, you'll need to supply the X-Vault-Token header to your HTTP request, and that token must have sufficient permissions at the sys/mounts/kv path.

https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/system/mounts#enable-secrets-engine

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I resolved by running the
`vault login` command
and provide the token.